# Problem when using GIT REVERT (CONFLICT deleted in empty tree and modified in HEAD)

Tags: git, git-revert

I am a git beginner and I ran into a problem with GIT REVERT.
Here is the steps that I took:

```
mkdir new-repo
cd new-repo
git init
echo "first line" >> test.txt
git add .
git commit -m "first line added"
echo "second line" >> test.txt
git add .
git commit -m "second line added"
```

Then, to try out and learn how things work in git, I tried to give a git revert, to see if I could get back to the version of the file test.txt that only has the first line in the file, so I used:

`git revert HEAD~1`

but then, it gives the error:

```
CONFLICT (modify/delete): test.txt deleted in (empty tree) and modified in HEAD.  Version HEAD of test.txt left in tree.
error: could not revert b88b72d... first line
hint: After resolving the conflicts, mark them with
hint: "git add/rm <pathspec>", then run
hint: "git revert --continue".
hint: You can instead skip this commit with "git revert --skip".
hint: To abort and get back to the state before "git revert",
hint: run "git revert --abort".
```

And even if I git add test.txt and doesn't allow me to complete the revert, and I get stuck infinitely in this REVERTING operation status. If I do git rm test.txt, it allows me to complete the revert, but in this case I end up with no file test.txt in my workplace. That's not what I would like. I would like to have the test.txt with only the single line, after completing the revert. What am I doint wrong? and what should I do to get what I want in this case? I appreciate any help!

I tried git add test.txt but it doesn't work, and I remain stuck on the revert.

Comment: Side note: `git revert` if for creating a new commit that reverses the changes of a past commit. If instead you want to undo the last commit so that it "never existed", you can use `git reset HEAD~1`

Comment: I think I got it that git revert doesn't do what I expected. But, a new question emerges:
Is there a command in git that specifically enables me to get all my working dir back to the state it was at a certain commit in time? (withou deleting the commits, as in the case of "git reset --hard idcommit". In the context of my question above, suppose I have ten commits, each one adding a new line to the file. Since I am in the 10th commit, what would be a command for me to type, for example, to get my working dir exactly equals it was at the 3rd commit, withoud deleting the commits 4 through 10?

Comment: That would be `git switch --detach <commit>` (or `git checkout <commit>`). See also [`git switch --detach`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt---detach) and [git checkout DETACHED HEAD](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head)

Answer (score 3):

1. To abort the revert, run

```
git revert --abort
```

2. After that, you need to revert the correct revision:

```
git revert HEAD
```

When you revert, you are basically applying a reverse diff, and you need to give Git something that identifies that diff.

In Git, `HEAD` refers to the latest commit on the current branch, and `HEAD~1` refers to the second latest. So by doing `git revert HEAD~1` you were trying to revert the first commit (that of `first line`, which is the second-latest) rather than the second commit (that of `second line`, which is the latest).